# Need Help on How to calculate address size in Hexadecimal

Tags: memory-address

i did cat /proc/meminfo then i find
000a0000-000bffff : Video RAM area
here the size is 20000 how is this calculated?

Answer (score 0):

The calculation is

```
 000bffff
-
 000a0000
 --------
    1ffff
```

which is 131071 in decimal (and one less than 20000 hex).

Did you mean 20000 to be a hex number?

Comment: dont know plz go through this link http://beefchunk.com/documentation/sys-programming/os-programming/how_do_i_determine_the_amount-of_ram.html